# Monitor background process from website

Tags: php, mysql, process-monitoring

I have a website on which people can request certain files to be processed, the processing is done on my server and then the processed files are made available to download. I'd like to enable administrators of my website to see from the website whether or not the processing code is running, has failed, is waiting, etc.

So I imagine I'd like to just have a line on the webpage that says "Waiting", "Active", "Failed", etc. I expect it would use php.

That's the general outline, in particular this is how my system works:

• When a user chooses a processing job it is added to a mysql database using php.

• A python code called monitor_database.py is running in a screen instance, it monitors the database and starts the appropriate processing job when it notices that the database has a new request in it.

• Once the processing has been completed the database is updated.

So I'd like to be able to see from my webpage whether or not the screen session and my monitor_database.py are running, and whether or not monitor_database.py has sent anything to be processed, or is waiting.

Has anyone any suggestions about how best to achieve this?

Comment: What have you considered/tried?

Comment: @NevilleK Nothing, I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not adopting to IE, you could use WebSockets for this.

This answer is as general as your question is ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into WebSockets.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way of doing this is with Ajax calls. Check out how many travel sites show you a status screen while they search for flights, for instance.

The exact way you'd do this is highly dependent on the application, but in principle you have a "status" page (which could be the page on which your users upload their files). The status page contains JavaScript which every 30 seconds calls a PHP script on your server; the PHP script in turn queries the database to find the status of the current file, and returns a bit of XML or JSON. The JavaScript on your web page interprets that XML or JSON, and updates the page with the result. There's more description [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009664/php-display-progress-messages-on-the-fly). There's sample code [here](http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=h307/ajaxstatus.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I finally went for...

First I created a new mysql table on my database that contains only one row, describing the status of my code (waiting, doing this, doing that, etc.)

Now I have this php code on my page:

```
exec( "ps aux | grep process_name.py | grep -v grep | grep -v emacs", $pids );
// This looks for any processes named 'process_name.py', ignoring those caused by emacs,
// and the one caused by grep itself.
$r_process = @mysqli_query($database, "SELECT status FROM process_status WHERE status_id=1");
// This checks the status of the file in the database.
$Monitor = mysqli_fetch_array($r_process);
$StatusName = $Monitor['status'];
if ( empty($pids) )
    {
    $Status = 'Failed';
    }
else
    {
    $Status = 'Operating';
    }
```

Now, in my html, I can have a thing that shows 'Failed on process1' or 'Operating on process2', depending on how my process is proceeding. I have to refresh my page to get it to change. I believe earlier answers assumed that I wanted to avoid having to refresh the page and were suggesting ways to avoid that, but really I just wanted an easy way to check if the process was running. the `exec ( gps... )` was the key.